# Are there any Linux networking C APIs to process each network packet as a user before routing them?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, firewall, nat

I am writing some code to create a "semi-public Wi-Fi network" with user credentials.

I say semi-public as it is still a private Wi-Fi network (all traffic is encrypted) but it is set up as public in the Wi-Fi interface, to be able to connect without a Wi-Fi password.

On my server/router side, I need to intercept each packet, check its rights, and then re-dispatch it or drop it. For that I have used IOCTLs and set up a ("middle-router") tap interface that captures packets on each subnetwork and forwards or drops them as appropriate. That works great: packets on one subnetwork can't go to another one without being processed by my code. But I can't keep an app from sending unauthorized and unencrypted packets to the networks (without setting a rule in iptables to redirect everything to my tap interface except my API itself?).

But I think that way seems to be a kind of "hack". What I would like to do is to make the kernel call my code to perform the routing step.

Comment: libpcap can do network packet analyzing stuff. But your approach looks kind of man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: kind of ^^, but it is quite like a rooter works no ?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to design a *captive portal*. Maybe using that as a search term will help.

Comment: indeed, it's part of the project, but a captive portal doesn't keeps ethernet packets from beeing send inside the server